# Qlikview user cannot see report but others can

Tags: qlikview

I have been hit with a curve ball, where a user who could see a Qlikview report can no longer see the data. The user is not getting access denied or anything like that, he just not seeing any of data. Basically an empty graph.

Nobody is experiencing this issue, and everyone has the same access.

The distribution service and server has been restarted and it is not clearing the problem.

User access is via Windows Authentication. A colleague found that the user was actually getting a http 401 when trying to access this report. No data was being pulled into the report when the user tried. Of course none of this happens when accessing another report.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you check that user Current Selections are empty (meaning that we sure that, by mistake, the user hasn't applied a weird filter to the document)?

Comment: The same user from a different browser ou device, also shows an empty dataset?

Comment: It's the same trying from different browsers and workstations. No filters applied as the problem is only visible when clicking on the link to the report. Further, the user has reported to me that he had another report on another screen and all of a sudden the data just went.

Comment: However, for other users they are not seeing any problems this is even closing browsers and starting up again

Comment: Even if he open the report there is no data, a filter could be applied and saved in the user session. If I do a filter in one report on my server, close it and open it again, the same filter is still applied. The user can check the Current Selections on the top bar of the document.

Comment: I don't think the filter is the issue. This is because the selection boxes to create the filter are all empty. So in other words it's an empty report like a template with no data

Comment: In the server you'll find a .shared file alongside the qvw document. Rename it (from <file>.shared to <file>.tmp for instance) and ask the user to check again. This file should contain user specific details related to document acess, renaming will force QVS to recreate it.

Comment: We tried recreating . shared files but with no luck. A colleague of mine has found that when the user tries to access the report he is seeing http to 401 unauthorized error and is not getting back any report. This is different when he accesses another report that does work. Any ideas from anyone